# How to convert from json to pdf and generate PDF on the FLY using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, json, jspdf

What I need to do is something like this. I Need to convert JSON data to pdf and then generate a pdf to send to clients via email. I am using **nodemailer** to send emails and **jsPDF** to convert from JSOn to PDF.I am able to convert but when i am using doc.save() then it is first storing the pdf then sending it to client.

What i want is that when client click the button then coversion of JSON should occur then PDF generation should occur on fly and pdf should be sent to client.

Basicaly i do not want to store file in database, i want the conversion and generation and then sending should occur on fly. and after sending email there should be no PDF File.

I will be happy from any answer that help me in converting From JSON to pdf and generation of PDF and then sending the pdf without storing it in my local storage or database.

I tried with **doc.output()** but i don't know that can it be helpful so Anyone knows Please Help.

Language - JAVASCRIPT , NodeJS(Framework)

Comment: Does email have to be involved? Why not just generate a browser download?

Comment: No, Email is required because Button click will be done by Manager and File has to be sent to Assosiate so email is required. And They don't want it to store so things should be done on the fly.

Comment: Ok. So generate a temporary PDF file, append it to the email, and after sending it, delete the temp file.

Comment: That's the same thing i also thought of. But my boss wants it to done on The FLY. So is there any way in jsPDF i can do this on The FLY.

Comment: The question is: can jsPDF create a Buffer, and can nodemailer attach a Buffer. First question: [yes](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output). Second question [also yes](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/)

Comment: I got your point @Chris G and i am very thankful to you for that. But can you or someone please expalin it a bit better. Or if someone can give a code demo then it will be very best for me because this is first time i am using jspdf and nodemailer.

Comment: Use `arraybuffer` as the output type for jsPDF and plug the result into `content` when you add the attachment. Unless this is also your first time writing JavaScript, you should be able to manage that yourself ;)